# current sourcing by MSP430F5438A-EP MCU

Tags: microcontroller, msp430

I am using the MSP430F5438A-EP microcontroller. I wanted to know the max current that could be sourced by this chip. The datasheet is -[Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f5438a-ep.pdf).

The data given in page 38 states - Diode current at any given pin = 2mAmps. The diode, I believe, is the protection snubber circuit in each GPIO. Right ?
Hence, I am safe in assuming that each pin can source a max of 2mAmps ?

[image: Absolute rating.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's how much current will destroy the voltage protection diodes if a voltage above or below the maximum values is applied to a pin.

The maximum current available is described on page 44, in and just below the "Outputs – General Purpose I/O" tables.

Comment: But this gives the total current supplied by the chip. Not the individual pin max current sourcing. I am looking at the max current that can be sourced.

Comment: Also, the chart states some of the test conditions as -3mAmps. What is this negative sign for ?
Also, if the snubber circuit (protection dioodes ) are blasted if the current is more than 3mAmps, how can they test it at -3mAmps ?

Comment: @VinodKaruvat the current on page 44 is the current that can be sourced from an IO pin - what other method is there of sourcing current? You asked for "I wanted to know the max current that could be sourced by this chip" and this, as far as I can tell is what you want.

Comment: sorry, wrong chopice of words. my bad. I want to know the max current that can be sourced by any GPIO of this chip.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat the protection diodes are when the IO is an input. Sourcing current is different to diode clamp current.

Comment: You have your answer @VinodKaruvat

Comment: So, lookingg at the table(Outputs – General Purpose I/O (Full Drive Strength)
) in page 44, what I see is that they have test conditions of -3mAmps,-6mAmps and uppto -15mApms.
So, from this I am assuming that although the max current sourcing can be as high as -15mAmps, the sum total cannot exceed 100mAmps. Now, what does this negative sign denote ?

Also, in the test conditions of the said table, we see that at Vcc = 3V, I(ohmax) = -5mAmps and a max of 48mAmps, but at the same time at 3V and I(ohmax) = -15mAmps a max of 100mAmps. How is this possible ?

Comment: @VinodKaruvat: How much current you can source depends on what voltage drop you can tolerate. See the tables for details.

Comment: As per my previous commen, in both the case the drop is 3V, yest the max current sourced by this chip is 48mAmps and 100mAmps.

Comment: Did you actually read the values in the "MIN" and "MAX" columns?

Comment: @VinodKaruvat the max current of 100mA is for the sum total of GPIO pins used to source (or sink) current. Each pin can say source 10mA but no more than (say) 10 pins can be used for doing this.

Comment: And what does the negative sign denote ?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103894/understanding-74lvc245-datasheet-and-current-source-sink/103900#103900

Answer (score 2):

There is no single number.  The current depends on supply voltage, high level output voltage V<sub>OH</sub>, temperature.  Fortunately, the datasheet provides curves like this:
[image]
([pp.45-46 in the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f5438a-ep.pdf))

### Related

[Similar discussion about MSP430G2210.](http://www.edaboard.com/thread342286.html#post1460439)
[Discussion about digital output current in PICs.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/186024/7036)